# Inserting contents to the last row

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to insert data to the last row of my table. But it’s doing it 4 rows later.
Here my code :

```
'  ------ FR020 -----

'Variable pour trouver la dernière ligne
Dim DernLigne As Long
DernLigne = Range("A1:Q1").End(xlUp).Row

' Insérer valeur FR020 en A
Range("A1" & DernLigne).Value = "FR020"

' Insérer valeur 03700 en D
Range("D1" & DernLigne).Value = "03700"

'Insérer valeur 59800019FR en E
Range("E1" & DernLigne).Value = "59800019FR"
```

Here the table :

[image: Excel Table]

Comment: Can you please specify (by edit) where exactly you want to "insert" your new data and if you want to keep values of the existing last row by shifting it down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to go `xlUp` from the very last row of the worksheet `Range("A" & Rows.Count)`

Any you need to change `Range("A1" & DernLigne)` into `Range("A" & DernLigne)`

```
Dim DernLigne As Long
DernLigne = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'remove the +1 to overwrite the last data row

' Insérer valeur FR020 en A
Range("A" & DernLigne).Value = "FR020"

' Insérer valeur 03700 en D
Range("D" & DernLigne).Value = "03700"

'Insérer valeur 59800019FR en E
Range("E" & DernLigne).Value = "59800019FR"
```

---

The problem was that `Range("A1:Q1").End(xlUp).Row` resulted in row `1`

and this `Range("A1" & DernLigne)` appended this `1` to `A1` so it got `Range("A11")`.

Comment: Side note: Think OP wants to "insérer", i.e. insert *before* the last row (*dernière ligne*)

Comment: *"I would like to insert data to the last row of my table"* well that can mean the last row that already has data or the next free row (which would be a simple `+1`).

Comment: yes,... even this seems possible (see OP mentioning a 3 rows offset first).

Comment: Hi all ! Thanks a lot @Peh. Yes, sorry for my english. I updated my code and added +1 and now it works perfectly !